# JetBrains Rider Entity Framework Update Model from Database

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, rider

I have been trying to find the option to update model from database using Entity Framework 6.2 on JetBrains Rider 18. This option is available on Visual Studio, but I can't find any such option on Rider. Anyone have any idea about this?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you even open an EDMX in Rider? I mean, with design surface and all, not as XML file.

Comment: Hi Gert! No, I can't. I can only see it in the XML format, as you mentioned. I think I might still need to use Visual Studio just for this feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Until now, Jetbrains Rider do not provide this functionality. If one really wants this, then your best bet would be to either try some external reverse engineering tools, or to use Visual Studio instead.